# HQL, use @ in alias

Tags: hibernate, hql, alias

I'm trying to run this query

```
SELECT userType from Users as @type
```

But hibernate throws a syntax error.

> org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@'

I tried to use quotes but it didnt work as well.

Can this be done?

Comment: Why you want to use @ instead a simple alias?. For me the correct use is select myalias.userType from Users myAlias

Comment: The API Im using returns a map of the columns vs alias. I want this map to have '@type' as a key, automatically, without having to do it manually. Also, our json deserializer uses the '@type' key to identify the object's type.

Comment: Hey @FabioK, did you overcome the issue? I'm facing the same while trying to use dots (inside quotes) in an alias for an hierarchical transformer.